# How to skip blank rows in maatwebsite-excel 3.1 for model-way import on Laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm working on laravel project with `maatwebsite-exvel 3.1` to import excel file from file uploding method. This is my `StudentsImport` class.

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Student([
        'school_uuid' => Auth::user()->school_uuid,
        'cardid'     => $row[0],
        'prefix'    => $row[1], 
        'name'    => $row[2], 
        'lastname'    => $row[3], 
        'dob'    => $row[4], 
        'address'    => $row[5], 
        'phone'    => $row[6], 
    ]);
}
```

And below is controller.

```
 Excel::import(new StudentsImport,  $request->file('file'));
```

Code work fine. I can import excel's data to database but blank rows also imported. I would like to filter/validate to skip these blanks before put to database. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a workaround which helps in my case. Validation is extended by nullable on all rows to avoid errors and then In the method, I have added below code and it worked

```
public function model(array $row) 
{
  if(!array_filter($row)) {
     return null;
  } 

  // your code will be here
   return new Student([
        'school_uuid' => Auth::user()->school_uuid,
        'cardid'     => $row[0],
        'prefix'    => $row[1], 
        'name'    => $row[2], 
        'lastname'    => $row[3], 
        'dob'    => $row[4], 
        'address'    => $row[5], 
        'phone'    => $row[6], 
    ]);
```

and skip these rows at this point. Not really happy with this as I cannot return an useful error message but as I found no solution the best way to get the code running.
I found this from here.
https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/1861#issuecomment-520753182

Answer (score 6):

As per the [package documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html), support is provided for using Laravel's validation to prevent invalid rows from being inserted.

To use it, implement the `WithValidation` interface on your importer class and add a `rules()` method that return the validation rules that should be used to ensure that the row is valid.

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        '0' => 'required|string',
        '1' => 'required|string',
        '2' => 'required|numeric',
        // so on
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please note, the `rules()` method does not skip empty rows, but throws an error which leads to failure of import and the rows which where validated will be rolled back.

However i found this feature exist in the documentations, simply you have to implement this to your import class: "Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure"

Like this for exemple:

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure {
    // Your import class
}
```

Then define a method within your import class to handle the errors:

```
/**
 * @param Failure[] $failures
 */
public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures)
{
    // Handle the failures how you'd like.
}
```

Now the `rules()` method won't throw errors anymore on empty rows and you can handle errors silently, you should still be using the `rules()` method tho, simply because you need it to throw the errors which are now able to be handled by you, perhaps you could log them to a file or however you do it normally.

In the end you will be able to collect all errors, here is an example from the docs:

```
$import = new UsersImport();
$import->import('users.xlsx');

dd($import->errors());
```

So, now you can silently catch the errors and eventually return it to your request, you can even return detailed info like this:

```
foreach ($import->failures() as $failure) {
   $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
   $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
   $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
   $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
}
```

This is not copy paste material ok, i just explained how you can access the errors based on examples given in the docs, i leave it up to you to handle this data.

Here is a link to the docs where i found all this info: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#skipping-failures

Answer (score 1):

Try using ToCollection and then try if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty())

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
   {
      foreach($rows as $row) {
        if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty()){
            // you logic can go here
           }
        }   
   }
```

Don't forget to include `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;`
It worked for me perfect

Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1861#issuecomment-457144438).

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip rows base on the validation that you make. You can put in your model a return null if one of your requests ar not cover

```html
public function model(array $row)
{
    if ($row[2] === null || $row[3] === null ...) {
      return null;
    }
    return new Student([
        'school_uuid' => Auth::user()->school_uuid,
        'cardid'     => $row[0],
        'prefix'    => $row[1], 
        'name'    => $row[2], 
        'lastname'    => $row[3], 
        'dob'    => $row[4], 
        'address'    => $row[5], 
        'phone'    => $row[6], 
    ]);
}
```

And also you can add in the rules in the required field an validation rule "required_with" if in other fields exists something the validation will drop and if don't exists to skip the row returning null in the model area.

```html
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        '0' => 'required_with:*.1,*.2,...', // here to be the others rows if they are populate to trow an validation error, 
        '1' => 'string|nullable|required_with:*.1,*.2,...',',
        // so on
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a collection and use it with a filter rather than an array. First trim the value as a space is not empty. Then make it a collection after that filter the empty row.

```
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $em1=trim($row[0]);           

        $em = collect([$em1]);
       

        if($em->filter()->isNotEmpty()){
            // you logic can go here

            $user = Content::create([
                'email'     => $row[0],
                'phone'    => $row[1],
                'first_name'    => $row[2],
                'last_name'    => $row[3],
                'zip_code'    => $row[4],
                'address'    => $row[5],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `maatwebsite-exvel 3.1`, you can use **SkipsEmptyRows** concern to skip empty rows

like this :

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Imports;
    
    use App\Models\Student;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
    
    class StudentsImport implements ToModel, SkipsEmptyRows
    {            
        public function model(array $row)
        {
           return new Student([
            'school_uuid' => Auth::user()->school_uuid,
            'cardid'     => $row[0],
            'prefix'    => $row[1], 
            'name'    => $row[2], 
            'lastname'    => $row[3], 
            'dob'    => $row[4], 
            'address'    => $row[5], 
            'phone'    => $row[6], 
          ]);
       }
    }
```

as mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#skipping-empty-rows)

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore the empty row by updating the config/excel.php file.

from:

```
'ignore_empty' => false,
```

to:

```
 'ignore_empty' => true,
```