# How to remove blank line in csv file using laravel maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I want to export csv file using Maatwebsite in laravel. The process is running well, but in the csv file contains blank line in last data when i open it using notepad. Displayed at image below

[image]

This is the function to get the data

```
public function view(): View 
{
    $data = DB::table('transaction as a')
                ->join('transaction_details as b', 'a.id', 'b.header_id')
                ->select('b.order_number', 'b.changed_number')
                ->whereIn('a.id', $this->id)
                ->where('a.approve', 1)
                ->get();
    
    return view('vendor.voyager.transaction.excel-csv.generate-csv', [
      'data' => $data
    ]);
}

public function getCsvSettings(): array
{
    return [
        'enclosure' => ''
    ];
}
```

This is function to call the function above

```
public function generate(Request $request)
{

    $id = $request->ids;

    return Excel::store(new ExportTransaction($id), 'test.csv', 'ftp');
}
```

How to solve my problem to remove blank line in the csv fie

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212305/how-to-skip-blank-rows-in-maatwebsite-excel-3-1-for-model-way-import-on-laravel help?

Comment: @NigelRen Not working, it's still have blank line