# Issue with Importing Excel Data (Collection rows) to Laravel 9 Database using maatwebsite/excel 3.1

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to import multiple rows from an excel sheet using Maatwebsite-excel 3.1.
Here, is the challenge, when I do. `dd($row)` it prints all the rows. However, the moment I am not running the code without DD, it magically "empties" the rows.
Below is my code

```
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $rows->shift();

        $total_amount = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row){

            if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty()){
                $article_title =collect(trim($row[0]))[0];
                $tag = collect(trim($row[1]))[0];
                $words = collect((int) $row[2])[0];
                $deadline = collect(trim($row[3]))[0];
                $pkw = collect(trim($row[4]))[0];
                $skw1 = collect(trim($row[5]))[0];
                $skw2 = collect(trim($row[6]))[0];
                $instructions = collect(trim($row[7]))[0];
                $my_tag = UserTag::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$tag.'%')->first();
                $my_urgency = Urgency::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$deadline.'%')->first();
//                dd($tag, $words, $my_urgency);
                $amount  = $my_tag->amount_per_word * $my_urgency->amount * $words;
                $project_deadline = now()->addHours($my_urgency->hours)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                Project::create([
                    'user_id'=>request()->user()->id,
                    'article_title'=>$article_title,
                    'upload_batch_id'=>$this->batch->id,
                    'user_tag_id'=>$my_tag->id,
                    'urgency_id'=>$my_urgency->id,
                    'price_per_word'=>$my_tag->amount_per_word,
                    'no_of_words'=>$words,
                    'deadline'=>$project_deadline,
                    'amount'=>($amount),
                    'primary_keyword'=>$pkw,
                    'secondary_keyword_1'=>$skw1,
                    'secondary_keyword_2'=>$skw2,
                    'instructions' => $instructions
                ]);
                $total_amount = $total_amount + $amount;
            }
        }
        $this->batch->amount = $total_amount;
        $this->batch->update();
    }
```

I have also used tried it without `collect(trim(row[value]))` but this also did not work.

I have tried following [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212305/how-to-skip-blank-rows-in-maatwebsite-excel-3-1-for-model-way-import-on-laravel), but none of them worked for me

Here is the error
[image]

and below is my dd statement

[image]

Please help me kindly.

Comment: Ohh I forgot to mention that my Excel file has a list in it (select option). But that should not be a problem since in the  dd($row) I can see the values.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Implement `WithHeadingRow` to class then remove the `$rows->shift();`

This will make the first row array keys. Then you can access them later as:

```
class ProjectsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
   public function collection(Collection $rows){
        $total_amount = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row){

            if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty()){

                $article_title = $row['article_name'];
    }
  }
 }
}
```